# Exporting RBokeh Plot for Non-R Users

Tags: r, plot, export, interactive, rbokeh

I have created an interactive plot in R using the RBokeh package. How do I save it so that it is a file that non R users can open and use? So basically currently I can hover my cursor over points in the plot and other information pops up for each data point making it interactive. I want to keep that format instead of just saving it as a picture.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Sample code:

```
install.packages("stringi")
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

devtools::install_github("ramnathv/htmlwidgets")
devtools::install_github("bokeh/rbokeh")
library(rbokeh)
head(iris)
p <- figure() %>%
  ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris,
            color = Species, glyph = Species,
            hover = list(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
p
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding plot to web page using rbokeh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947668/embedding-plot-to-web-page-using-rbokeh)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. You can save it as an html file on your desktop and then you can email that file to whoever you please.

Comment: including code (i.e. the call to `saveWidget`) would be helpful to to others